# C# - Retrieve list of all ReadOnly files under a directory in Windows

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get a list of all ReadOnly files under a directory including files under sub-folders. Is there something in the .NET Framework which would make this easier than looping through all the files?

Comment: Easier than what? Show the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var path = @"C:\";//Some path
    var readOnlyFiles = new DirectoryInfo(path)
        .EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(file => file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a flag in `SearchOption.AllDirectories` in `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles`, which means a recursive search. Here's a way to do the stuff:

```
var readOnlyFiles =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles("base directory", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).IsReadOnly).ToList();
```

Comment: readOnlyFiles keeps getting updated if I change the read-only status of any file. I need a static list.